# Pandas rsplit with if contains

Tags: pandas, string, contains

> Using python with if contains(r'/' and r'\') and rsplit(str,1) I can
> separate the values. But using Pandas is not working.
> How can I get this result using pandas?

```
"PATH_IN","PATH_OUT"
"C:\USER\ARON\TESTE.TXT","C:\OUT\TESTE.TXT"
"SOUP.TXT","SOUP.TXT"
"/OPT/IN/TESTE.TXT","TESTE.TXT"
```

Result

```
"PATH_IN","NAME_IN","PATH_OUT","NAME_OUT"
"C:\USER\ARON","TESTE.TXT","C:\OUT","TESTE.TXT"
"","SOUP.TXT","","SOUP.TXT"
"/OPT/IN/","TESTE.TXT","","TESTE.TXT"
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the dataframe to the question.

Comment: i add dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to *avoid* regex and use `os.path.split`, since it can handle multiple separators for filenames.

```
df[["PATH_IN", "NAME_IN"]] = df["PATH_IN"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(os.path.split(x)))
df[["PATH_OUT", "NAME_OUT"]] = df["PATH_OUT"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(os.path.split(x)))
```

Output:

```
        PATH_IN PATH_OUT    NAME_IN   NAME_OUT
0  C:\USER\ARON   C:\OUT  TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT
1                          SOUP.TXT   SOUP.TXT
2       /OPT/IN           TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT
```

Comment: Using lib os would i have problem with operating system or version of python?

Comment: Most unlikely. `os.path.split` is specifically designed to **not** have a problem across multiple platforms that `str.split` may have. It also handles if a path is a basename only (e.g. `soup.txt`).

Comment: I used the code with the expression but it raised an exception. TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not float

Comment: Feel like there is an empty cell hence `np.nan`. Use `df = df.fillna("")` before you apply the code

Comment: 1st Thank you very much for your help!
works, but the processing time is very long, about 4 minutes. Is it possible to improve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['NAME_IN'] = df['PATH_IN'].str.split(r'[/\\]').str[-1]
df['NAME_OUT'] = df['PATH_OUT'].str.split(r'[/\\]').str[-1]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  PATH_IN          PATH_OUT    NAME_IN   NAME_OUT
0  C:\USER\ARON\TESTE.TXT  C:\OUT\TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT
1                SOUP.TXT          SOUP.TXT   SOUP.TXT   SOUP.TXT
2       /OPT/IN/TESTE.TXT         TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT  TESTE.TXT
```

Comment: I need the results to be unique. In path only path and filename only filename.